# System of quadratic equations for a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

I know the dimensions of the base of a tetrahedron and the angles between the non base sides at the apex.  I want to know the lengths of the three non base sides. Let the base's corner points be $A, B,$ and $C, $ and the apex be $O$.  I have used the law of cosines to create three equations:
$$|AB|^2=|AO|^2+|BO|^2-2\cdot |AO|\cdot |BO|\cdot \cos(\angle AOB)$$
$$|BC|^2=|BO|^2+|CO|^2-2\cdot |BO|\cdot |CO|\cdot \cos(\angle BOC)$$
$$|CA|^2=|CO|^2+|AO|^2-2\cdot |CO|\cdot |AO|\cdot \cos(\angle COA)$$
Let:
$$X=|BC|^2,Y=|CA|^2,Z=|AB|^2,a=|AO|,b=|BO|,c=|CO|,$$
$$\alpha=2\cdot \cos(\angle BOC),\beta=2\cdot \cos(\angle COA),\gamma=2\cdot \cos(\angle AOB)$$
Now the equations can be written:
$$0=b^2+c^2-\alpha b c-X$$
$$0=c^2+a^2-\beta c a-Y$$
$$0=a^2+b^2-\gamma a b-Z$$
I tried to solve this system using the quadratic formula, but the equations became far too large by the time I had it in terms of a and there were three groups of $\pm$.

**My main question:** Is there a better way to solve this system than the quadratic formula?  Also, is there a better way to solve the tetrahedron than my law of cosines method?

Comment: You are using $A$ to mean both a point and a number. Please do *NOT*!

Comment: I don't really know how to do vectors, but I'm not sure this would work because I know the angles between the rising sides and each other, not the rising sides and the base.

Comment: Just to clarify things, you have the angles between the *edges* at the apex, not the [dihedral angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) between the *faces*, right? If you look at the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), then you can see that the locus of all points $O$ which satisfy *one* of the angle conditions would be a circle (or arc) in the plane, but actually a self-intersecting spindle [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) in 3D. So you are intersecting three such objects, for which a quadratic approach looks perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Yes, the angles are between the edges at the apex, not the faces (not dihedral).

Comment: By the [Spherical Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), if you know the face angles at the apex, then you can find the dihedral angles at the apex, and vice-versa.